# Prevent PHP leaking variables with include or require

Tags: php, arguments, include, require

I have unwanted arguments leaking into my `template.php`.

```php
function template($template, $args) {
  $foo = $args['bar'];

  extract($args);

  include __DIR__ . '/' . $template . '.php';
}
```

In the `template.php`

- `$foo` should **not** print out something because it's not extracted from `$args`.
- `$bar` should print out something because it's extracted from `$args`. It does.
- `$template` should **not** print out something because it's not extracted from `$args`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?= $foo; ?>
<?= $bar; ?>
<?= $template; ?>
</html>
```

In real life the HTML above is valid. Also, I have much more arguments in the `template` function.

How can I get around argument leaking? I could change scope by wrapping `include` in another function but then I still need `$template` which will then be passed to the `template.php`.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you include a file, it's roughly equivalent to putting the code of the file in place of the `include` statement. So it can access any variables you assign. If you don't want it seeing `$foo`, don't assign it.

Comment: This is why the best practice for include files is that they should just define functions, which you call from the main program. The function parameters define the interface, and other variables will be ignored.

Comment: @Barmar Well, yes. That could be avoided but my include is dependent on a variable to be able to use the correct file. I can't get rid of $template. It's still accessable.

Comment: There's no difference between variables that are assigned with `extract()` and parameter variables or ordinary assignments. Perhaps your include file shouldn't require the variables to be extracted in the first place, it should just use the associative array directly.

Comment: What does the template itself do?  Are you including all variables currently in scope or something else?

Comment: You can `unset` the variables - but you could also just name the variables (e.g. with an underscore prefix) so template don’t accidentally reference these internal variables.

Comment: @NigelRen I just pass down some arguments to the template to be able to use them there. I can also nest snippets inside of the templates and pass variables to them as well. Maybe I should look into how WordPress does it.

Comment: Here's [a reference](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/View/View.php#L1165-L1191). Note that if `$args` in the question includes `template` you'll end up rendering a different template file.